# Close Details tag only for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

What is the simplest solution to close the  tag opened by default from mobile?

I use Wordpress. How could I do?

```
<details open>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

Answer (score -1):

> CSS is used for designing and formatting HTML elements. You can't manipulate HTML elements here like changing it's attributes.

> Javascript is most suitable for HTML elements manipulation.

If you really don't want to use JS in what you are doing right then, just create two details tag and hide one when it's on mobile screen and hide one when it is on large screen.

Something like this:

```
<details class="hide-sm" open>
    <summary>Big Screen Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>

<details class="hide-lg">
    <summary>Mobile Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

But to be honest don't hesitate to use JS because you can do a lot of things when you use it side by side with CSS.

Comment: Thanks, yes in fact so it is not very usable, if I wanted to use JS how could I do? I use Wordpress.